# How to see PDF bookmarks in Safari

Tags: safari, pdf

When I view a PDF with Preview I can toggle on Table of Contents to see the bookmarks for sections and chapters. If I use Safari to read the PDF how can I see the table of contents?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't see the table of contents in Safari. To see the table of contents open the PDF in Preview.

This is not the answer you want, sorry about that.